# ERROR CREATE statement SQL SERVER : FK PK

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I create table KetQua but it shows message: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_KetQua_SinhVien". The conflict occurred in database "ThucHanh2", table "dbo.SinhVien", column 'MASV'.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are inserting in column 'MASV' in table 'KetQua' doesn't exists in table 'SinhVien'. As 'MASV' is the primary column of 'dbo.SinhVien', value must be there to satisfy your reference